# Jest mock not always works in async test

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function and I want to test it using Jest.

```
function handleRegister() {
    return (req, res) => {
  
      try {
        const credentials = {
          login: req.body.email,
          password: req.body.password
        }
  
        res.status(201).send({ msg: 'User registration achieved successfully' })  //LINE 10
        res.status(201).send({ msg: 'User registration achieved successfully' })  //LINE 11
  
        auth.register(credentials, (err, result) => {
          console.log('register', auth.getUsers())
  
          if (result.status === 201) {
            res.status(201).send({ msg: 'User registration achieved successfully' })  //LINE 17
            console.log('User registration achieved successfully')
          }
        })
    } catch(err) {

    }
}}
```

My test code is:

```
test('should return status 201 and msg', done => {

  try {
    const fun = handlers.handleRegister()

    const res = {
      status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      send: function () {
        done()
      }
    }


    fun({ body: { email: 'a', password: 'a' } }, res)

    expect(res.status).toBeCalledWith(201)

  } catch(err) {
    done(err)
  }
})
```

The problem is that function handlerRegister line 10 and 11 is correctly executed, but at line 17 I got an error:

```
/home/anna/Desktop/dev/exampleShop/backend/handlers.js:149
          res.status(201).send({
                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at auth.register (/home/anna/Desktop/dev/exampleShop/backend/handlers.js:149:26)
    at addAccountToDB (/home/anna/Desktop/dev/exampleShop/backend/auth.js:69:7)
    at addAccountToDB (/home/anna/Desktop/dev/exampleShop/backend/auth.js:81:3)
    at hashPassword (/home/anna/Desktop/dev/exampleShop/backend/auth.js:68:5)
    at AsyncWrap.crypto.scrypt (/home/anna/Desktop/dev/exampleShop/backend/auth.js:87:5)
    at AsyncWrap.wrap.ondone (internal/crypto/scrypt.js:43:48)
```

If I use js, not a mock in property res, like:

```
    const res = {
      status: function(){return this},
      send: function () {
        done()
      }
    }
}
```

then I don't have this error.

Can someone explain me what is wrong?

Comment: You should look into using an HTTP testing framework rather than manual mocks. Like [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) or [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest). Don't be scared off, they're really easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

There is a scoping issue. `res` is not defined where you are calling `res.send()`, because `res` is being defined inside of the `try` block.

Either move your expect statement inside of the `try` like below, or define `res` in the same scope as your `expect` statement.

Also you can't call `.toBeCalledWith` on a function that is not a mocked function. So notice that I have defined `res.send` to be a mock function, and instead calling `done()` at the end of your expect statements.

```js
test('should return status 201 and msg', done => {

  try {
    const fun = handlers.handleRegister()

    // res only exists inside of the `try`
    const res = {
      status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      send: jest.fn() // << is now a mock function
    }

    fun({ body: { email: 'a', password: 'a' } }, res)

    expect(res.status).toBeCalledWith(201)

    // here `res.send` is now defined, and you can use `toBeCalledWith`
    expect(res.send).toBeCalledWith({ msg: 'User registration achieved successfully' })

    done();

  } catch(err) {
    done(err)
  }
})
```

Comment: Sorry, this out of scope expect was not important, I have deleted it.

Comment: I don't understand, why when 'send' is defined as anonymous function I get undefined from 'status' return. When I define 'send' as jest.fn() then 'status' returns correctly 'this' object.

Comment: Also I don't understand why you add 'done()' inside 'try' scope, instead of callback

Comment: 1. when you define `send` as an anonymous function, it will have it's own `this`, which will not have `status`.
2. if you call `done()` in `send`, that means `done()` will be being called *before* your `expect` statements. `done` marks the end of the test, and should be called after your assertions.